# Prevent clicking on scene game objects through UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

In my scene I have a game object (CosmicCrystal) with BoxCollider2D and Sprite Renderer components that you can click/tap on to generate currency.

When you click on the menu buttons at the bottom of the screen, a CharactersPanel which is a game object with Canvas Group component is being enabled (alpha=1, interactable=1, blockRaycasts=1) and it pops over the screen.

It should be a no-brainer that the blockRaycasts on the CharactersPanel would block the clicks on the crystal when UI is enabled, but it still happens.

I've tried different approaches like creating a BlockPanel game object in between them, changing sort order to higher for the canvas, but it won't work.

I'd like to avoid using EventSystem solution which checks if mouse is over a game object.

Appreciate any help on this.

Attaching 4 screenshots showing the inspector panel for objects in question.

Screenshots:

[Crystal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7wLs.png) | [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caaqL.png) | [Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beWju.png) | [Expanded Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTCOg.png)

Thank you

Comment: Try grabbing the Images in the CanvasGroup and disabling "Raycast Target".

Comment: In every possible CanvasGroup or a specific one?

Comment: The `Raycast Target` is on the Image